# python matplotlib subplot no muestra nada

Tags: python, pandas, funciones, matplotlib

Tengo un dataframe de pandas que tiene varias columnas(bola, x, y) y quiero que a partir de los valores únicos de la columna bola haga un subplot para a continuación unirlos todos en un mismo gráfico.

```
def printManyLinearPlot(df):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    for i, col in enumerate(df.bola.unique()):
        dfcolor=df.loc[df['bola'] == col]
        plt.subplot(1,3,i+1)
        plt.plot(dfcolor['x'],dfcolor['y'], label=col)
        plt.xticks(df.index)
        plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()
```

Con el código anterior se genera el plot pero no muestra nada. ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Comment: Checa la parte de Examples (https://matplotlib.org/3.3.2/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html), ahí podrás tener una mejor idea de cómo dibujar los subplots.

Comment: Ninguno de los ejemplos de la web me sirven

Comment: Probablemente no las estás implementando como se deben, porque acabo de hacer uno y funciona correctamente. Lo dejo como respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya que no adjuntaste una copia de tu DataFrame o de su estructura, he creado uno de prueba.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {
        'bola': [
            'rojo',
            'verde',
            'rojo',
            'azul',
            'verde',
            'azul',
            'rojo'
        ],
        'x': [
            12,
            14,
            23,
            24,
            12,
            23,
            34
        ],
        'y': [
            1.2,
            2.1,
            2.45,
            .5,
            .23,
            4.3,
            2.32
        ]
    }
)
```

Y para hacer los subplots, hice lo siguiente:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)
for i, color in enumerate(df.bola.unique()):
    subset = df[df['bola'] == color]
    ax[i].plot(subset['x'], subset['y'], label=color)
```

El resultado se ve así:

[image: Subplots]

Ojo, el parámetro `sharey=True` permite compartir el eje Y entre los subplots, si lo quitas, cada uno tiene un eje Y independiente.